# Include error in visual studio code, using linux mint

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

> I can't run my programs in vs code, due to the include error that appears in my terminal, stating that stdlib.h, stdio.h, etc. "No such file directory".

There are many videos showing how to solve this problem, but they are in windows. So I came here to
know if anyone knows how to solve my problem. Here are some pictures of what's happening.

[This is the error that is occurring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIY8I.png)

[Here are the properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b8YG.png)

[Here are the configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m3Cl.png)

Added the extension of Microsoft C/C++ extension in hopes to solve this, but to no avail.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: The extensions alone are insufficient, you also need a full compiler installation, as in either GCC or clang.

Comment: show your tasks.json. this is a build error and not an intellisense error

Answer (score 1):

My problem as been solved with the following command: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.